# Incrementar ao chamar função javascript

Tags: javascript

Ola.

Eu gostaria que a cada vez que eu chamar a função seja incremntado o valor de ( i ) e exibido no alert, não sei oque estou fazendo errado.

Meu codigo;

```
function incrementar()
{
var count = 0.
count++;
alert(count);
}
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função sempre vai exibir o valor **1**, pois o algoritmo está setando o valor da variável **count** para zero toda vez que a função é executada.

Você pode resolver o problema da seguinte maneira:

```js
var count = 0;
function incrementar() {
  alert(++count);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 2):

Você está redefinindo o contador a cada vez que chama a função, porque está abrindo `var count` dentro. Defina `count` antes, como no exemplo, pra que a mesma variável esteja disponível sempre que for chamada.

```js
var count = 0;
    
function incrementar() {
    count++;
    // use console.log ao invés de alert para ver os resultados 
    // no console do navegador, aperte F12 no Chrome para ver o console.
    console.log(count); 
}

incrementar();
incrementar();
incrementar();
incrementar();
```

Comment: Legal, mas eu preciso que o valor incrementado seja global para eu poder utilizar em outras funções do javascript. Pensei em definir assim fora da função ( var totalIncremento; ) dai dentro da função fazer assim ( totalIncremento = count++; ). Daria certo isso

Comment: Nesse caso o valor incrementado já é global, dentro do escopo que você passou. Se você precisa de um valor que seja realmente global, pra ser acessado por outros escopos, outros scripts, pode usar `window.count = 0` antes e `window.count++` dentro da função.